# Is it possible to run Adobe Product Recommendation (Sensei) locally?

Tags: magento2, environment-emulation, adobe-sensei, product-recommendation

I would like to test one of the product recommendation scenarios locally. Can I run it in my local environment with HTTPS and the keys pointing to my staging server data source?

[image: Magento Adobe Sensei locally]